# Job preferences save doesn't work and refresh results accordingly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

The jobs preferences page refreshes the background jobs that are displayed once you click the save button.  The issue is they don't match my preferences.

Also the "Need Visa Sponsorship" checkbox never gets saved when you check it.  When one saves his / her preferences and the screen refreshes the jobs how come the matches don't really go into effect?  Is there some sort of timing?

Here is a screen print of my preferences:

[image]

I've tried to click "Need visa sponsorship" just to test and it does nothing.  I also added tech I don't want to work with (I dislike) and I have "matches" set on the grid that shows me jobs yet I still get php / ruby jobs.

Comment: Are you using any filters in your search or is it the default empty search?

Comment: "Need visa sponsorship" is tied to each individual location and should appear with a globe icon below the "Where you'd like to work" area (like Michigan is displayed with a house icon in your example).  That would happen on clicking the Add button.  Checking "Need visa sponsorship" and clicking Save wouldn't accomplish anything.  Perhaps the UI could be clearer here.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things here:

- there *is* caching involved but it's invalidated as soon as preferences are saved and propagated across the entire web tier using redis pub/sub so it's unlikely to be causing a problem.
- most of these preferences factor into a weight that is applied to a job which affects the sort order. Disliked tags effectively weight the jobs to be at the end of the search.
- **Need visa sponsorship** applies to a particular location (as Andrew mentions). You need to enter a location, check the box if you need a visa for that location and click add. If you need a visa you'll have a small globe in the location 'tag':

[image: Job Preferences]

I cloned your preferences and used some trickery to make it look like I'm coming from the same IP as you last logged in with and I see no [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) or [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) jobs in the list.